# How to keep element centered when window is resized

Tags: css

When I resize the window both the boxes remains left aligned as shown in the picture.

How to bring them in center?

[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JxYwg/3/) | [screenshot](http://s23.postimg.org/f7ooh01ij/flex_box.png)

```
div { 
    position: relative;
    outline: 1px dotted gray;
}

div #span1 { 
    background: green;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    padding: 30px 30px;
}  
div #span2 { 
    background: green;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px 50px;
}  
div .left {
    position: relative;
    left: 0; 
    top: 0;
}
div .right {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}
```

*********** HTML ***********

```
<div>
    <div class="two-columns">
    <span class="left" id="span1">1</span>
    <span class="right" id="span2">2</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text-align:center` ? **[DEMO, + vertical align](http://jsfiddle.net/JxYwg/9/)**

---

`display:inline-block;` **is not** `display:flex;` . Maybe your title question should be updated :)

---

For `display:flex;` it would be : `justify-content:center;` **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JxYwg/5/)**

For info, in flexbox model, `margin:auto` to verticaly center element is avalaible as for horizontal centering **[DEMO CENTER x,y](http://jsfiddle.net/JxYwg/8/)**

Comment: oh! Sorry for that! Actually code needed to be updated. Thanks for the answers. But what I want is when i make the window very small block two should be placed below block 1. And they should be centered Vertically.

Comment: @Kartikey , i updated the demo links, for display:flex, explanation and demo was already there :)

Comment: @Kartikey Does this answer your question ?